# using the app didReceiveRemoteNotification handler to get the push notification message

Tags: objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to get the message that was displayed to the user via remote notifications using with this implementation of the app did recieve remote notifiactions method?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        NSString *message;
        // code to set the string "message" to the remote notification's message...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it by accessing the JSON that was parsed in the userInfo Dictionary, If you print out your userInfo Dicitonary object like so:

NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", userInfo);

You'll get all the info you need.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I have been racking my brain to try and work this out so I figured I would share the knowledge to save someone else the time.

First off you should create an NSString reference of your text so you can access it later on quickly. To do that:

```
NSString *alertMessage = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
```

If you need to do this for local notifications you would do the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];

NSString *alertMessage = [[dict objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];

//Do something here
}
```